# How big does it take to use "in the west of"

Tags: phrase-usage

I read it [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/on-the-west-side-of-on-the-west.2964157/) that 'west of the campus' is not idiomatic because a campus is not big enough. Is this true? How big does it take to use "in the west or north of a place". Does it have to be no smaller than than a city or town? For example, can I say:

> The playground is in the west of the neighborhood.

Or do I have to say:

> The playground is on the west side of the neighborhood.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's just when you google grammar related questions, what rank in search results are always answers in language forums.

Comment: Do not rely on unknown people in language forums (even 'senior' ones!). You can talk about being 'in the north/east/south/west' of towns, their suburbs, and larger sites such as parks or factories. Possibly anything much smaller might be unsuitable, but a campus sounds big enough.

Comment: Please see my altered comment.

Comment: Although with smaller things (houses, malls, estates, maybe campuses) you'd probably say "it's on the west **side** of the house/mall/etc" or "the west **side** of the house overlooks the garden", not "the west of..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word in "in|on the west ____ of ____" that indicates the area must be relatively large is **in**.  The area must be large enough to *contain* other discrete areas and to support cardinal direction.

> The theater is **on** the west side of campus.
>
> The plains are **in** the west side of the province; the east is mountainous.

But this choice has less to do with the *absolute* size than with the terms the speaker is using to describe the situation. If the noun refers to a discrete area, we could use **in**:

> The infirmary is located **in** *the southwestern corner* of campus.

That would imply that the southwestern corner is large enough to contain multiple buildings.

> The infirmary is located **on** *the southwestern corner* of campus.

There, the infirmary could be the only building on the SW corner.

Space is relative.  Chromosomes are **in** the nucleus of a cell. But there we don't have cardinal direction. We wouldn't speak of the west side of a cell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about "**at** the southwestern corner of campus"? What does "at" imply?

Comment: Give me a sentence, not a phrase.  Phrases in isolation are of not much use.   *He was standing at the SW corner* is different from *He was looking at the SW corner*.

Comment: In your "infirmary" example, can I use "at"? **The infirmary is located at the southwestern corner of campus.**

Comment: Yes, that is very close in meaning to "located on the southwestern corner".